# The code doesnt work. The toggle is supposed to work but it doesnt invoke the class. Developer option doesnt give me any clues

Tags: jquery, css

****This code doesnt work I have included all the js files into the code but still the login toggle didnt work. Even developer options doesnt give us any clues on this.**

```js
$('.navbar-toggle').click(() => {

  $('.navbartab').toggleclass('.navbar-tab--open');

})
```

```css
.logoimage {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 5rem;
  filter: drop-shadow(12px 14px 10px grey);
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  left: 3rem;
}

.logo {
  font-family: font-family: 'Unkempt', cursive;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 12rem;
  position: relative;
}

.navbartab {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #ee5d5d;
  color: rgb(255, 175, 71);
  padding: 1.4em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navbartab ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbartab a {
  color: yellow;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 6em;
  text-decoration: thistle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbartab a:hover,
.navbartab a:focus {
  background-color: red;
  color: rgb(71, 255, 117);
}

.navbartab Li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbartab Li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid coral
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ee5d5d;
  padding: 2rem;
  right: .75rem;
  top: .75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggle,
.menu-toggle::before,
.menu-toggle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgb(211, 219, 219);
  height: 3px;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu-toggle::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.menu-toggle::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.navbar-tab--open {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">


      <h1 class="logo">FamilyShop</h1>
      <img class="logoimage" src="su-30mki-iaf-fb.jpg">

      <nav class="navbartab">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">contact</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">career</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">aboutus</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">feedback</a></li>


        </ul>

      </nav>

      <div class="navbar-toggle">
        <div class="menu-toggle"></div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: You wrote `toggleclass` but it should be `toggleClass` with capital `C`

Comment: Don't you see the errr message in the console?

Comment: Hello Barmar, I get $ is not defined error on the develope roptions.

Comment: Balastrong, It helped .. Thanks a ton. I shud be careful in future on jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should attach click handler when jQuery is loaded and dom is ready i.e. `$(function(){ ... here ... });`.
2. `toggleclass` is actually `toggleClass`.
3. The argument of `toggleClass` is the class name `navbar-tab--open` but not the class selector `.navbar-tab--open`, so it is `toggleClass('navbar-tab--open')`.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.navbar-toggle').click(() => {
    $('.navbartab').toggleClass('navbar-tab--open');
  })
});
```

```css
.logoimage {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 5rem;
  filter: drop-shadow(12px 14px 10px grey);
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  left: 3rem;
}

.logo {
  font-family: font-family: 'Unkempt', cursive;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 12rem;
  position: relative;
}

.navbartab {
  background-color: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-tab--open {
  height: auto;
  z-index: 10000
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #ee5d5d;
  color: rgb(255, 175, 71);
  padding: 1.4em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.navbartab ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbartab a {
  color: yellow;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 6em;
  text-decoration: thistle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbartab a:hover,
.navbartab a:focus {
  background-color: red;
  color: rgb(71, 255, 117);
}

.navbartab Li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbartab Li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid coral
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ee5d5d;
  padding: 2rem;
  right: .75rem;
  top: .75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggle,
.menu-toggle::before,
.menu-toggle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgb(211, 219, 219);
  height: 3px;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu-toggle::before {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.menu-toggle::after {
  transform: translateY(3px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="logo">FamilyShop</h1>
      <img class="logoimage" src="su-30mki-iaf-fb.jpg">
      <nav class="navbartab">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">contact</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">career</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">aboutus</a></li>
          <li> <a href="">feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="navbar-toggle">
        <div class="menu-toggle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```